# Draggable item faded and ugly

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I am working on some HTML5 drag-and-drop functionality. I add the `draggable="true"` property to my elements and it works great, up until the elements are wider than 300px.

Up to 300px wide, the "ghost" image that is shown while dragging looks good.

Above 300px wide (e.g. at 301px), the "ghost" image has a gradient fade starting from the mouse position.

```
<div draggable="true" style="width:300px">Item 1</div>
<div draggable="true" style="width:301px">Item 2</div>
```

"Item 1" above looks nice, "Item 2" above looks horrible. I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C3L95/1/) to illustrate the point. (Tested in Chrome and Firefox.)

[image: Nice Looking]
[image: Ugly Looking]

Is there any way to disable this, so I get the nice unfaded ghost image? I specifically want to drag around a div that is 400px wide.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot that illustrates the "ugliness"? On my mac  in Chrome both elements look exactly the same when dragged, even when I change the width of the second one to 400px.

Comment: Sorry, I added some screenshots. I have been testing on Windows. I just tested on my Mac and you are correct, it looks fine there.

Comment: Yeah, tested on Windows and I see that the element is faded away from the dragging point. I guess it is meant to show the user where he would be dropping that large element. One possible solution can be to copy the behaviour of google image search: when you click to expand an image and drag the large one, it creates a small version of the dragged image that is not faded.

Comment: I check it with IE, firefox and chrome, and always 301 px shape has gradient (windows 10). According to @pckill ` On my mac in Chrome both elements look exactly the same`, I can suppose this is windows issue. ps, edge has no this effect.

Comment: @chowey it's not just width. there must be some other conditions that trigger this because while in the same browser I can reproduce both cases in his JsFiddle but in my project I only get the ghost version no matter what I do

Comment: see? http://jsfiddle.net/zkms9pbr/ as soon as the draggable div is contains more than just one element it happens.

Answer (score 10):

In the future w3c plans to let user set all those effects by CSS4 new pseudo-selectors http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#drag-pseudos but now I think it's no possibility to style it normally. Only not using html5 feature `draggable` and let (some) javascript do all the job.

It's strange why someone from Google decided that elements bigger than 300px need some 'ghost' effect and smaller not.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think it might be how Windows works natively. It isn't Google-specific... Firefox does the same thing. But the CSS4 stuff might allow me to resize the draggable content, getting around the Windows built-in limitation on this.

Comment: Actually on second read, these selectors apply to the drag-and-drop target, not on the thing being dragged.