# image fading out when size is big using HTML drag

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

We are using drag & drop feature of HTML.

As you can see div width is `410px` and if start dragging this div, its ghost image of it fades out completely. I have big/large images to display while dragging them and as they are big in size they start to fade out completely. Is there any problem ?

---

If I change div width to `210px` then the ghost image looks fine. Then what's the problem with `410px` is there any limit to it? If yes, how can I increase it ?

```js
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
    els[i].addEventListener('dragstart', function (e) {
        e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.innerText);
    });
}
```

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    background: orange;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true" style="width:410px">Item 2</div>
```

Comment: There's a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841228/draggable-item-faded-and-ugly) regarding this problem. It seems to affect Windows 10 only and elements with a width greater than 300px.

Answer (score 1):

hide original image using event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(new Image(), 0, 0);
on dragstart. onDrag get the ghost image, update position using event.pageX, evenet.pageY

```js
onDrag(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const parentElement = <HTMLDivElement>(document.querySelector('.darggable-ghost-wrapper'));
    parentElement.style.position = "fixed";
    parentElement.style.left = event.pageX  + "px";
    parentElement.style.top = event.pageY + 5 +  "px";
    parentElement.style.opacity = ArhitectUtlityConstants.GHOSTPREVIEW.ghostOpacity;
    parentElement.style.border = "1px solid green !important";
}
```

Comment: hi where does this `ArhitectUtlityConstants.GHOSTPREVIEW.ghostOpacity` come from?